# Display the Cache Memory

Tags: android, caching

I want to display the cache memory of the installed application on the device. Is it possible to do so ?

Comment: cache memory of your own app or all apps?

Comment: Of all apps which are installed on device.At this time i am able to display the list of installed applications in front of that i want the cache memory of that app

Answer (score 0):

You cant show cache memory of all apps. Since the folder resides at

> /data/data/[packagename]/cache

, this is accessible only to the owner i.e to the application only. You will need root access to show these files

Comment: how to get the root access ? Because in my application I also want to clear the cache of the other apps so I think which will help me

Comment: @user1522869 u don't need access it.just delete the file inside the cache folder..